# CSS smooth transition for an icon move

Tags: css, squarespace

I'm looking for CSS to make an image transition 5px to the right smoothly. I have the move and opacity sorted, but am unsure how to make it run smoothly and not seem like a big jump when hovering.

Have the following code but don't really know how to do the transition correctly. Any help is much appreciated!

```
.naviconmain {
  transition: all 2s ease;
  opacity: .7;
  display: block;
  align: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.naviconmain:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  left: 4px;
}
```

Comment: add this line of code in your hover
`transition: left 0.5s ease;`

Comment: why don't you use `transform: translateX(4px)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help - very much appreciated. I've gone with:

```
.naviconmain {
  transition: all 2s ease;
  opacity: .7;
  display: block;
  align: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 15px;
 }
.naviconmain:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(4px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```